# Height of a Tree

Tags: java, recursion

i have 2 implementations for a height of a Tree:

```
public int height() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + Math.max(leftChild.height(), rightChild.height());
    }
}
```

and :

```
public int height2() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        int leftHeight = leftChild.height2();
        int rightHeight = rightChild.height2();
        if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
            return leftHeight + 1;
        } else {
            return rightHeight + 1;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Both are working but i dont understand the second one. How does he compare 
leftHeight > rightHeight if they never get a number before?

Thanks!

Comment: *"How does he compare leftHeight > rightHeight if they never get a number before?"* But...they do. On the previous two lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "if they never get a number before"? These variables get values assigned in the very lines before.

Comment: Yep, the second one uses `!isEmpty()` where yours use is `isEmpty()`

Comment: I suspect this isn't completely correct when one child is null and the other is not. Also, this isn't recursion since the original method isn't used within itself. It's just iteration

Comment: But int leftHeight = leftChild.height2(); and rightHeight = rightChild.height2(); dont get a number just calls the method again, and will both get the number 0, so how is 0 > 0?

Comment: @Kiimarii Are you sure they will both get the number 0? Hint: they won't.

Comment: @cricket_007 [_"Recursion in computer science is a method where the solution to a problem depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem (as opposed to iteration)."_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) This looks a lot like the definition of recursion, while iteration would be more like a for loop

Comment: @cricket_007 You must be reading the code wrong. The method `height2` is calling the method `height2` recursively on the children of the node, in both code snippets.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt My definition of recursion would look like `int height(Node n) { return 1+ Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right)); }`.. i.e. the *initial method* called within itself, not referenced from another object.

Comment: Tree traverssl is one of the most commonly referenced use cases for recursion. Example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal to exclude that from your definition makes it a very limited, and private, definition

Answer (score 3):

In both examples, the logic is:

1. If the node is empty, return 0
2. If the node isn't empty:

   1. Get the height of the `leftChild` node (recursively)
   2. Get the height of the `rightChild` node (recursively)
   3. Once we have those, compare them to decide which is greater
   4. Return the greater one plus 1

The second example just does the `Math.max` in longhand using a comparison, instead of passing the values into `Math.max`. There's no difference in *when* the function gets the height of `leftChild` and `rightChild`.

I recommend stepping through the code statement-by-statement in a debugger to see when the recursion happens and when the values are available.

Here's an example in JavaScript (language doesn't really matter here, this is about recursion) which may make it clearer:

```js
let indent = "";
class TreeNode {
  constructor(name, leftChild = null, rightChild = null) {
    this.name = name;
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
  }
  isEmpty() {
    return this.leftChild == null && this.rightChild == null;
  }
  height2() {
    indent = "  " + indent;
    console.log(indent + "Getting height of " + this.name);
    try {
      if (!this.isEmpty()) {
          let leftHeight = this.leftChild.height2();
          let rightHeight = this.rightChild.height2();
          if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
              console.log(indent + "Done, height of " + this.name + " is " + (leftHeight + 1));
              return leftHeight + 1;
          } else {
              console.log(indent + "Done, height of " + this.name + " is " + (rightHeight + 1));
              return rightHeight + 1;
          }
      } else {
          console.log(indent + "Done, height of " + this.name + " is 0");
          return 0;
      }
    } finally {
      indent = indent.substring(2);
    }
  }
}
const t = new TreeNode(
  "top",
  new TreeNode(
    "middle-left",
    new TreeNode("bottom-left-left"),
    new TreeNode("bottom-left-right")
  ),
  new TreeNode(
    "middle-right",
    new TreeNode("bottom-right-left"),
    new TreeNode("bottom-right-right")
  )
);
console.log(t.height2());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```